# no matching function call std::basic_ofstream<char>::write()

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm trying to accomplish binary i/o here and I keep getting this error which is...

```
no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(int*,unsigned int)'
```

and

```
no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(double*,unsigned int)'
```

Here is my code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 123;
    double fx = 12.34;
    ofstream myfile("filename.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    myfile.write(&x, sizeof(x));
    myfile.write(&fx, sizeof(fx));
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I've found multiple other posts with the same situation but their fix was usually typing in...

```
ofstream myfile(filename.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
```

The compiler still screams at me as I tried it multiple times. I'm using QT creator as my IDE which I've already verified it is using C++11. and also ran the same code in Code::Blocks and get the same error. Its not liking the filename parameter i'm passing to it. I think this has something to do with the first parameter being the const char of the member function of ofstream open()?!

```
void open(const char *filename, [int mode], [int prot]);
```

What am I not understanding/missing here?

Comment: What you're missing is that there are no `write` overloads for every type you can think of. If you want to do binary I/O, you should be explicit about it by casting the pointer to memory that holds the object to `const char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write()` is a function for outputting characters, it won't apply any formatting, you need to do the formatting yourself.

The function requires a `const char*` argument. It won't take pointers to other types, a conversion will need to be made first.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) for more details.

The stream operator `<<` is better suited if you want the stream to format your output.